# JPA Updates Part of A Record And Returns No Error

Tags: java, jpa, sql-update

I have a java web application using JPA. My problem seems simple but has stumped me for a day now. 
I have two tables in my database, Book and Author.
Both input fields in the view for these tables are in the same form.

What's weird is when I update (mrege()) the edited record the book will update but the author does not. I've debugged and followed the author object as far as netbeans will let me and when I merge() my new book record, only the Book table/object are effected.

The Book is a Many-To-One

The Author is a One-To-Many

**Controller**

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");

    try {

        String action = request.getParameter("action");

        if (action != null) {
            List<String> values;
            try {
                values = new ArrayList<>();

                switch (action) {

                    case "save": //                                 Ecompasses Save and Update
                        Book book = null;
                        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                        Date date;

                        String bookAuthorID = request.getParameter("authorID");
                        String bookID = request.getParameter("bookID");
                        String title = request.getParameter("title");
                        String userEnteredDate = request.getParameter("datePublished");
                        Author author = null;

                        if (bookID.matches("\\d+")) {            // Update

                            book = bookService.find(new Integer(bookID));
                            book.setTitle(title);
                            book.setDatePublished(sdf.parse(userEnteredDate));

                            author = authorService.find(new Integer(bookAuthorID));
                            author.setAuthorFirstName(request.getParameter("authorFirstName"));
                            author.setAuthorLastName(request.getParameter("authorLastName"));
                            book.setAuthorID(author);

                            bookService.edit(book);


                        }
  }
```

**Author Entity**

```
 @Entity
 @Table(name = "Author")
 @XmlRootElement
 @NamedQueries({
 @NamedQuery(name = "Author.findAll", query = "SELECT a FROM Author a"),
 @NamedQuery(name = "Author.findByAuthorID", query = "SELECT a FROM Author a WHERE a.authorID = :authorID"),
 @NamedQuery(name = "Author.findByAuthorFirstName", query = "SELECT a FROM Author a WHERE a.authorFirstName = :authorFirstName"),
 @NamedQuery(name = "Author.findByAuthorLastName", query = "SELECT a FROM Author a WHERE a.authorLastName = :authorLastName")})
 public class Author implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "AuthorID")
private Integer authorID;
@Size(max = 50)
@Column(name = "AuthorFirstName")
private String authorFirstName;
@Size(max = 50)
@Column(name = "AuthorLastName")
private String authorLastName;
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "authorID")
private Collection<Book> bookCollection;

public Author() {
}

public Author(Integer authorID) {
    this.authorID = authorID;
}

public Integer getAuthorID() {
    return authorID;
}

public void setAuthorID(Integer authorID) {
    this.authorID = authorID;
}

public String getAuthorFirstName() {
    return authorFirstName;
}

public void setAuthorFirstName(String authorFirstName) {
    this.authorFirstName = authorFirstName;
}

public String getAuthorLastName() {
    return authorLastName;
}

public void setAuthorLastName(String authorLastName) {
    this.authorLastName = authorLastName;
}

@XmlTransient
public Collection<Book> getBookCollection() {
    return bookCollection;
}

public void setBookCollection(Collection<Book> bookCollection) {
    this.bookCollection = bookCollection;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 0;
    hash += (authorID != null ? authorID.hashCode() : 0);
    return hash;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object object) {
    // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
    if (!(object instanceof Author)) {
        return false;
    }
    Author other = (Author) object;
    if ((this.authorID == null && other.authorID != null) || (this.authorID != null && !this.authorID.equals(other.authorID))) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "edu.wctc.asp.bookwebapp.bookservice.Author[ authorID=" + authorID + " ]";
 }

 }
```

**Book Entity**

```
 @Entity
 @Table(name = "Book")
 @XmlRootElement
 @NamedQueries({
 @NamedQuery(name = "Book.findAll", query = "SELECT b FROM Book b"),
 @NamedQuery(name = "Book.findByBookID", query = "SELECT b FROM Book b WHERE b.bookID = :bookID"),
 @NamedQuery(name = "Book.findByTitle", query = "SELECT b FROM Book b WHERE b.title = :title"),
 @NamedQuery(name = "Book.findByDatePublished", query = "SELECT b FROM Book b WHERE b.datePublished = :datePublished")})
 public class Book implements Serializable {
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "BookID")
private Integer bookID;
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Size(min = 1, max = 50)
@Column(name = "title")
private String title;
@Column(name = "DatePublished")
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date datePublished;
@JoinColumn(name = "AuthorID", referencedColumnName = "AuthorID")
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
private Author authorID;

public Book() {
}

public Book(Integer bookID) {
    this.bookID = bookID;
}

public Book(Integer bookID, String title) {
    this.bookID = bookID;
    this.title = title;
}

public Integer getBookID() {
    return bookID;
}

public void setBookID(Integer bookID) {
    this.bookID = bookID;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public Date getDatePublished() {
    return datePublished;
}

public void setDatePublished(Date datePublished) {
    this.datePublished = datePublished;
}

public Author getAuthorID() {
    return authorID;
}

public void setAuthorID(Author authorID) {
    this.authorID = authorID;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 0;
    hash += (bookID != null ? bookID.hashCode() : 0);
    return hash;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object object) {
    // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
    if (!(object instanceof Book)) {
        return false;
    }
    Book other = (Book) object;
    if ((this.bookID == null && other.bookID != null) || (this.bookID != null && !this.bookID.equals(other.bookID))) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "edu.wctc.asp.bookwebapp.bookservice.Book[ bookID=" + bookID + " ]";
 }

 }
```

Comment: did you apply cascade operation?

Comment: @Ish, that actually broke the program.

Comment: what do you mean broke the program? is there any error or specific behavior you observed?

Answer (score 0):

Apply `CascadeType.MERGE`:

```
@JoinColumn(name = "AuthorID", referencedColumnName = "AuthorID")
@ManyToOne(optional = false, cascade=CascadeType.MERGE)
private Author authorID;
```